# How to create unique dictionaries in a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I'm relatively new to Python. I have a ton of files, and for each one of them I want to create a dictionary with information about the file. My current code is this:

```
thespefiles = glob.glob('*.SPE')
for filename in thespefiles:
    barename = filename.replace('.SPE', '')
    #does operation to retrieve outputwpsx and outputwpsz
    #does operation to retrieve value

    barename +'_dictionary' = {
        'filename': filename,
        'barename': barename,
        'readcounts': value,
        'wpsx': outputwpsx,
        'wpsz': outputwpsz,
    }
```

However, it comes up with an error with the line `barename + '_dictionary'` saying:

> "Syntax Error: can't assign to operator".

I understand that dictionaries are normally assigned without quotation marks, but when I used `barename_dictionary` instead, it said:

> "NameError: name 'plate2_008_006_dictionary' not defined"

(plate2_008_006 is one of the specific barenames) when I tested it outside of the whole loop.

SO, my question is, is there a way to create a bunch of unique dictionaries from a single for loop? I've looked everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your inner dicts inside an outer dict:

```
thespefiles = glob.glob('*.SPE')
file_dict = {}
for filename in thespefiles:
    barename = filename.replace('.SPE', '')
    #does operation to retrieve outputwpsx and outputwpsz
    #does operation to retrieve value

    file_dict[barename] = {
        'filename': filename,
        'barename': barename,
        'readcounts': value,
        'wpsx': outputwpsx,
        'wpsz': outputwpsz,
    }
```

Dynamic variable names are possible, but to be avoided. For cases like this it's better to use a container data structure like a dict to key to the inner dicts you're building.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that? You will have a bunch of new variables and you will have trouble to recognize and fetch them. Code you provided, neither first nor second is valid. You were trying to asign new value to a string (barename+"_dictionary") which is not possible. You can asign only new value to a variable or an object with **setitem**() method (eg. dictionary, list, ...).
In second case you were putting each new dictionary in a variable named "barename_dictionary". As barename already exists something weird happened. Why did this throw an error, I am not sure. In theory this shouldn't have happened. But, obviously it did and it is bad.

However, that what you would like to do is possible. Here is how it is done.

```
# There are two ways:
# 1. Construct the code string and execute it:
codestr  = barename+"_dictionary = "
codestr += "{'barename': 'blah-blah', 0: 1234}"
exec codestr
# Or (2.), simply add the new variable with a dictionary manually to a wanted namespace:
globals()[barename+"_dictionary"] = {"barename": "blah-blah"}

# In both cases variable names have to be within Python naming rules.
# Your filenames are a little odd for that. Change them!
```

Bare in mind what kojiro said. If you really don't have to, DO NOT DO THIS!